# express hot middleware creates a lot of bundles on root memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

update:

Seem I have solved my problem creating an "hot directory" in my webpack config like that :

My webpack.config.js :

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/public/",
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
  }
```

My new tree folders :

```
├── hot
├── package.json
├── src
└── webpack.config.js
```

But I still wonder how purely create these chunks in memory ? 
Any hint would be great,

Thanks

---

I'm trying currently to work with express hot middleware. I have set my webpack.config, server.js and package.json to work with. It works fine now but generates a lot of bundles on my root directory instead of on memory, hence saturate my root's directory. I can't figure out what is wrong.

The bundle have name like the following :

```
main.0d50bece383b2f7c93db.hot-update.js
```

They are created when there is a change on my server or more generally, configuration files it seems.

Here my webpack.js :

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path=require("path");

module.exports  = {
  mode:"development",
  entry: [ 
  "webpack-hot-middleware/client",
  "./src/client/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
        }
      },
      {
        test: /js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loaders: "babel-loader",
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "css/[name].css"
    }),

    new (webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin || webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin)(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.BROWSER': true,
    }),
  ],

};
```

here my server.js :

```
app.use(
  require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  })
);

app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));


// main route 
app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"))

    compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.set('content-type', 'text/html');
      res.send(result);
      res.end();
      });

});
```

my package.json :

```
 "scripts": {
    "starter": "nodemon ./starter.js",
    "start-dev": "concurrently --kill-others 'npm run webpack' 'npm run devserver'",
    "devserver": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server.js",
    "webpack": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --w --hot --inline",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production webpack & NODE_ENV=production node ./server.js "
  }
```

Any hint would be great,
Thanks

Comment: seems works better with Node instead of Nodemon. but the root's bundles are still here

Comment: try to remove `contentBase` option

Comment: Thanks, I have removed my dev  server but still compute bundles in root directory

Comment: using `webpack-dev-server` without `contentBase` option should serve from memory....

Comment: @ElmerDantas with `contentBase` it should also serve from memory, with the exception of  the files in `contentBase` dir.